# Completar padrão no Google Sheets

Tags: funções, microsoft-excel, google, planilha, fórmula

Tenho uma planilha com as colunas "Eduardo", "Márcio", "Rafael", etc.
Nas linhas, tenho fórmulas que seguem o padrão:

> Na primeira linha da coluna "Eduardo":
> =SE(OU(Vendas!C**2**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**3**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**4**="**Eduardo**");Vendas!C**1**/Vendas!C**5**;0)
>
> Na segunda linha da coluna "Eduardo":
> =SE(OU(Vendas!C**7**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**8**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**9**="**Eduardo**");Vendas!C**6**/Vendas!C**10**;0)
>
> Na terceira linha da coluna "Eduardo":
> =SE(OU(Vendas!C**12**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**13**="**Eduardo**"; Vendas!C**14**="**Eduardo**");Vendas!C**11**/Vendas!C**15**;0)
>
> Na primeira linha da coluna "Márcio":
> =SE(OU(Vendas!C**2**="**Márcio**"; Vendas!C**3**="**Márcio**"; Vendas!C**4**="**Márcio**");Vendas!C**1**/Vendas!C**5**;0)

Como dá pra perceber, os números das células pulam de 5 em 5, e os nomes estão de acordo com  a coluna, porém o Google Sheets não reconhece isso para eu simplesmente poder auto preencher. Existe alguma forma de eu automatizar a repetição?

Answer (score 0):

Ghesla, compartilha uma copia da sua planilha (ou mostra ela através de um print). Assim, fica mais fácil de desenvolver um raciocínio para a fórmula